# How do WiFi APs distinguish between text messages and media content for encrypted messengers?

Tags: encryption, wifi, whatsapp

I recently took a flight with Delta airlines. They offer in-flight WiFi for messenger services *iMessage*, *Facebook Messenger* and *Whatsapp* and state that

> Words and emojis accepted. Sending photos, videos or SMS messages is **not** supported.

Given the encryption for these services, most popular in the news being probably Whatsapp, I am wondering how they can distinguish the different content types. Maybe a cap on message size?

[image: Delta airlines Wifi description]

https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/onboard-services/delta-studio/in-flight-wi-fi.html

Comment: I think it’s message sizes, or more likely - data transfer rate.

Comment: @AndrewMorozko this would mean that choosing an image small enough would allow transmitting it? I should try this on my next flight

Comment: most definitely you would be able to do it. Only images are large by default, send something like 8x8 px for testing

Comment: Well, consider that SMS uses a completely different service, and maybe they haven't whitelisted the gateways needed for all carrier's WiFi calling.

Comment: @multithr3at3d to emphasize, my question is regarding the different content types **per** messenger. E.g. how they can allow messages to pass that contain text versus images for _WhatsApp_. I think it is clear that they can distinguish between the different services but what my question aims at is rather: what part of the communication can they see that gives them enough information to make this content type distinction?